# How search by title in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, search

please can you help me how do action which search posts only by title and sort by title.
I dont want change query search in include file query.php.

```
function sort_searchresult_by_title($k){
    if(is_search()){
        $k->query_vars['orderby'] = 'title';
        $k->query_vars['order'] = 'ASC';
        // some code for change search logic

    }
}


add_action('pre_get_posts','sort_searchresult_by_title');
```

Thank you,
P. V.

Answer (score 1):

By default, WordPress constructs the search query to look in the `post_title` and `post_content` fields. You can change it by hooking into [the `posts_search` filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.3/wp-includes/query.php#L1869), and creating a new SQL clause there.

Did you know that there is a [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), specific to all WordPress-related questions?